# How to refocus the camera on button click during record of video with Camera 2 Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I create a camera Android app using [googlesample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video). I need that camera will refocus on start of recording of video and each time the user presses on focus button during recording a video. Where can I find an example how to implement it?

This is my [Camera2VideoFragment](https://codeshare.io/5OdJ9j) and it's [parent](https://codeshare.io/adwAvK) class

Answer (score 0):

you need to add capture call back to add focus control to your camera session.

```
private boolean firstCaptureDone = false;
private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallback = null;

captureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);

            boolean cameraFocussed = false;

            private void process(CaptureResult result) {
                int afState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);
                if (CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START == afState) {
                    if (cameraFocussed) {
                        if (firstCaptureDone) {
                            firstCaptureDone = true;
                            Log.d(TAG, "firstCapture Done with focus");
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_PASSIVE_FOCUSED == afState) {
                    cameraFocussed = true;
                } else {
                    cameraFocussed = false;
                }
            }

        };


mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), captureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
```